# Convert DateTime.Now to MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, datetime-format

I am developing MVC app and I am using input type datetime-local of format [mm/dd/yyyy --:-- --] and i want set it max value of that input not greater than current today date and time but my validation max value datetime format and DateTime.Now does not much and does validate properly. and have tried more string formats, its validate only the date party only not with time party.
here my controller

```
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
 public DateTime AlarmEndDate { get; set; }
```

and my View input:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AlarmEndDate, new { @class = "form-control disabled", @type = "datetime-local", @max = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt}", DateTime.Now) })
```

Any help?.

**Edit**:

Ex: Converting a datetime like this: 7/22/2015 12:00:00 AM of SQL Server to 7/22/2015 12:00 AM of Input type datetime-local

Comment: Please format your question for readability. If you want to set a maximum date though, use one of the many DatePicker controls (eg from jQuery, Bootstrap) and set its maximum date. Text boxes are for text and have no min or max values.

Comment: Aside - `DateTime.Now` is the local time of your *server*.  It has very little usefulness in a web application.

Comment: I am using textbox of type datetime-local like input of type datetime-local and i don't want to use jQuery of datepicker.